# Javascript Quicksand slider

Tags: javascript, quicksand

I'm trying to include javascript cycle slider - Quicksand 1.2.1
But in the firebug console I'm getting this error:

```
$("#home_header ul").cycle is not a function
```

Can anyone help me with this?

here is the link to app http://mycompany.herokuapp.com

Comment: Are you getting a 404 in the net tab for the cycle JavaScript?

Comment: i believe no - please have a look at the app http://mycompany.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add this in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanx for your reply. I believe I've included this file. Please have a look at the site: http://mycompany.herokuapp.com

Comment: @Dantes your jquery should be before any script include

Comment: I believe I've corrected that mistake, but the previous error is still there. Please take a look at the same link

Comment: @Dantes make `cycle-6556170cff4f2d7f97486bb74287e736.js` first then `application-06d8fce4b0859d6166128af0830ed804.js`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/index.html)? According to the docs, it would be `$('#home_header ul').quicksand();`

Comment: I believe it's little bit adapted. Please take a look at this link: mycompany.herokuapp.com